# how to set format of  date picker in date (WebForm)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datepicker

I am using `Jquery` For Date Picker

```
<p>Date: 
   <input id="datepicker" ClientIDMode="Static" type="text" runat="server" /> 
   g.Date = datepicker.Value;
```

any one can guide me how to set the date format for date picker of VS using c#

i want to set format of 18/01/2011 to January 18, 2011.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
 datetimePicker.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
```

For various custom formats

> [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: yes, you can do this, for that you have set the value of customFormat at run time from the code weather in the constructor of on pageload event.

Comment: can u suggest the code for  customformat on pageload i am not getting.

Answer (score 0):

You should be interested in setting the [`CustomFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx) of the datetimepicker to suit your needs

```
dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker.CustomFormat="MMMM dd,yyyy"
```

In case of JQuery try something on these lines

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'format here'});
```